# Use redis as a database for rails application for high volume api requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I want to use Redis as the data store for handling high volume requests on a CREATE resource API, such that the model is saved in Redis and can be retrieved quickly while it can be written to PostgreSQL in the background using a SideKiq job. The create API should return the unique resource id along with other model attributes even if the background job is not yet complete. How can we achieve this in a rails application.

Comment: What kind of volume are you talking about? I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not, but you could use the jid from the sidekiq job.

Comment: Let's say for example we want to create an application for storing & retrieving IOT enabled thermostat readings. Now there can be multiple thermostats that would be calling the CREATE reading API very frequently & simultaneously. We want the API to be as fast as possible so we schedule a background job for writing to the DB. But even if the background job is not yet complete, the API should returns the created resource (reading in this case) with the unique id which can be used in subsequent requests (like GET /readings/:id).

Answer (score 1):

> should return the unique resource id

That's the main obstacle, I'm guessing? You could use client-generated UUIDs (where client is your API endpoint. It generates id, pushes id with data to redis and returns the id). The rest is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/soveran/ohm to create models based on Redis and create background jobs to fetch data from Redis based models and push them to your Postgres using ORM.